# not not not not True evaluates True, how?

Tags: python

How come not not not not True evaluates True? not quite understand its logic, it would be nice if anyone can help me to understand it. Thanks

I would like to see the logics behind this expression.

Comment: The expression is the same as `not (not (not (not True)))` which is then evaluated from the innermost parentheses outwards.

Comment: 2 `not`'s cancel each other.

Comment: Each `not` flips the boolean from `True` to `False` or `False` to `True`. Just work your way through the `not`s one at a time and there is no reason for it not to.

Comment: Do you understand why `not True` is `False`? Do you then understand why `not not True` is `True`?

Answer (score 1):

`not` operator will give the reverse result of the value follow it. Then, the result should be:

- True --> True
- not True = False
- not not True = not (not True) = not False = True
- not not not True = not (not not True) = not True = False
- not not not not True = not (not not not True) = not False = True